# No target available in Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed my eclipse 
when selecting target , It says no target available 
When I tried to add location in preferences , it says ADT is not up to date 
SO I updated it in help as well
there was no change 
SO I selected : "Install new software" in help and then at the end of the process, it says

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.7.2120684

How do i resolve this

Comment: Do you have an android platform installed via android sdk manager?

Comment: go to help > install new software > select adt > install

Answer (score 2):

**Step to do -**

1) Install latest packages from Android SDK (Main things required - Platform tools, Build Tools and latest platform(for example - Android API 23 Marshmallow))

2) Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.

3) Click Add, in the top-right corner.

4) In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:- `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

> Note: The Android Developer Tools update site requires a secure connection. Make sure the update site URL you enter starts with HTTPS.

5) Click OK.

6) In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.

7) In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.

8) Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

> If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

9) When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

> If the above doesn't work, get help from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

**PS -** Try using Android Studio. Also, if you like this answer, please mark it as `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio, restart the program > in the project menu, where you can for example start a new, or import a project,  choose configurations > SDK manager.

Here should be everything you need for downloading the proper build tools for your project.

Answer (score 0):

As it shows that there is a "conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.7.2120684". Then read the rest of the details about the problem, and search if it suggests any older version of the same file is already installed or not. In case of a conflict,

> > Go to BACK where you selected the ADT previously
> >     select already installed 
> >     uninstall the old version of those files of which the new versions are offered in new ADT version
> >     (i.e.: I was offered Hierarchy Viewer version 23, so i uninstalled Hierarchy Viewer version 17 and other items of older version 17 from "Already installed" link).
> >     Picture showed in the link -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ9Sa.jpg) & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi91W.jpg)

N.B.: You can compare the offered version and installed version as the picture showed in the link -> [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk72E.jpg)

> > after uninstalling all the old version items which cause confliction with new ones, close the "*Already installed*" window and hit the **NEXT** button and see if it still suggests any confliction. Which means you missed to uninstall any item of any older version of same file. 
> >     In that case compare again and follow the same procedure and go ahead.

Hope you will find your desired solution by following these steps. Thank you.